# Why do we need a viewport height for calculating Scroll Percentage?

Tags: jquery, scroll

As elementary as it might sound but I am having trouble understanding the concept of calculating scroll percentage.

```
return Math.ceil( ((scrollPosition() + viewportHeight()) / pageHeight()) * 100 );
```

So I got the formula from an online resource,but I don't understand why we need a viewportHeight parameter in the above formula?

I am surely missing something very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scrollPosition()` gets how far you have scrolled down the page, however, the measurement is taken from the top of the page. You need to add the `viewportHieght()` to take the measurement from the bottom.

Let me give you an example (hopefully this will explain better what is going on):

- The page is 1000px high
- The viewport is 200px high
- The user has scrolled down 500px (`scrollPosition() == 500px`)

The `scrollPosition()` takes the measurement from the top of the page. This is `50%` down the page (`500/1000 == 1/2 == 50%`). However, the user can see further than the top of their viewport. They can see all the way to the bottom of the viewport. So even through they have scrolled down `500px`, they can see `700px`, `70%` of the page.

So as you can see, without adding `viewportHeight()` you end up with a different (smaller, incorrect) result (`50%` instead of the correct `70%`)

Comment: That was helpful.I had understood the definition of scroll percentage wrong.I thought about it more as an absolute figure.